Integrating difference of Fermi-Dirac distributions
The following question comes from "Quantum Transport" by Nazarov & Blanter, which I'm self-studying for my research. Let
$$
f(E-\mu)=\frac{1}{1+\exp{[\beta(E-\mu)]}}
$$
be the Fermi-Dirac distribution, where $\beta>0$ is the inverse temperature. The first part of the question asks the reader to prove
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dE\,\left[f(E-\mu_L)-f(E-\mu_R)\right]
=\mu_L-\mu_R
$$
no matter what the value of $\beta$ may be. This part was no problem. The next part asks the reader to prove that the result above will still hold if the Fermi-Dirac distribution is replaced by some other distribution which approaches unity as $E\rightarrow-\infty$ and approaches zero as $E\rightarrow\infty$.
I'm a bit stuck on this part and I would very much appreciate a hint on how to proceed. I've tested the claim for several distribution functions meeting the above requirements using Maple; for example
$$
\begin{align*}
f_1(E-\mu)&=\frac12\left[1-\tanh{(E-\mu)}\right]\\
f_2(E-\mu)&=e^{-\left(E-\mu\right)^2} + \Theta(E-\mu)
\end{align*}
$$
and it does indeed appear to be correct.
EDIT: The distribution replacing the Fermi-Dirac distribution should be a function of $E-\mu$.

Note that your $f_1$ is just the Fermi-Dirac distribution with $\beta = 2$, so it's not surprising that it works.

You've already proven it for Fermi-Dirac distributions, so presenting the problem context as being that of "Fermi-Dirac integrals" doesn't seem ideal.

Does $f$ need to be a function of $E-\mu$?  Otherwise I don't see how this can work... $f(E,\mu_L) - f(E,\mu_R)$ would be completely arbitrary except for going to $0$ at $\pm \infty$.  (In particular, $f$ could just not depend on $\mu$ at all.)

@mjqxxxx Yes, $f$ should be a function of $E-\mu$. I've edited the notation in the question accordingly. Thank you!

Sketch of a heuristic argument:  draw the two curves.  The desired integral is the area between the curves.  If you then imagine subdividing this area into infinitesimally thin horizontal strips (like a Riemann sum but horizontal), each strip has width $\mu_L - \mu_R$, and the total height of the strips is 1, so the total area is $\mu_L - \mu_R$.  This might qualify as a "proof" in a physics textbook but it probably doesn't qualify over here.  :-)

One minor observation here: If you shift the definition of $E$ by $\mu_L$ (i.e., $E\mapsto E+\mu_L$) then the identity becomes $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dE[f(E)-f(E+\mu_L-\mu_R)]=\mu_L-\mu_R$. So one can just focus on the difference in chemical potentials and take one of them to be zero.

Also its a good idea to start with a finite integral and then take the limit in the end, i.e. $\int_{-E}^E (f(E'+\mu) - f(E'))dE' = \int_E^{E+\mu} f(E')dE' - \int_{-E}^{-E+\mu}f(E')dE'$. The two assumptions on $f$ can then be applied to give you the result.

One point of site context is that a version of this problem is considered here. However, in that case it was assumed that $f$ was a (cumulative) probability distribution, which is stronger than the assumptions imposed here. (The answer by drhab is possibly sufficient but is a bit obscure in its assumptions.)

Caveat: this answer is incomplete and may rely on unwarranted assumptions.  See the comment at the bottom.
Using the observation of @Semiclassical from the comments, we can focus on the case where $\mu_R = 0$.  We then define the function
$$
Q(\mu) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty [f(x - \mu) - f(x)] \, dx.
$$
We obviously have $Q(0) = 0$.  Moreover, taking the derivative of this function,* we have
$$
\frac{dQ}{d \mu} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial\mu} [f(x - \mu) - f(x)] \, dx = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x - \mu) \, dx \\= - \left[ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x - \mu) - \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x - \mu) \right] = 1.
$$
Thus, $Q(\mu)$ satisfies $Q'(\mu) = 1$ for all $Q$ and $Q(0) = 0$, meaning that we must have $Q(\mu) = \mu$.

*This step is obviously a big leap and one that I need to justify better, but unfortunately I don't have time to work through it just now.  I will return to this later if I can; comments on this step will be greatly appreciated.  This answer is on point; the assumptions boil down to:

$g(\mu, x) \equiv f(x - \mu) - f(x)$ & $\frac{\partial g}{\partial \mu} = -f'(x - \mu)$ are continuous in $x$ and $\mu$ (which seems like reasonable conditions to impose on $f$)
The integral converges for some $\mu$ (it obviously converges for $\mu = 0$ as shown above)
The improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x - \mu) \, dx$ converges absolutely (this is the assumption I'm not sure about; it's been a long time since Real Analysis)


I do wonder if this depends on the definition of integral being used, i.e., is it possible to come up with examples which are valid under the Lebesgue integral but not the Riemann integral. (The former feels more naturally suited here, since as you noted there's an obvious interpretation of the integral as a sum of horizontal strips.)

Thank you very much! This derivation is what most likely what my physics textbook had in mind. Since these questions about real analysis are out of my wheelhouse, I'm content to accept the answer. For the interested reader, a new question has been opened which seeks the precise assumptions on $f$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4952639/conditions-on-real-function-f-for-int-mathbbr-fxt-fxdx-t-for-al
